# Selenium Webdriver responding slow in quora.com

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I've been using Selenium (Python) for a long time now. Recently I've encountered something weird (for me at least):

when doing a simple find,

```
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
```

which would normally take no time, in https://www.quora.com/ it takes a long time ( couple of seconds) to be performed. It appears to happen anywhere in qoura, any action taken using Selenium takes a long time.

Does it got anything to with Selenium response to robot.txt???

Comment: Quora.com takes a while to load. Why do you think it's a performance problem on your end?

Comment: Selenium tends to wait for websites to be loaded before you can apply driver related methods. To my knowledge the loading,once finished, should not affect other selenium functions.

Answer (score 0):

Changed to driver = webdriver.Chrome(), problem solved, yet couldn't find the problem..